# CakePHP Howto allow value change from A to B but not vice versa (B to A)

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've created a form using the Form Helper and one of the fields is a select for values (for example) A and B.

When you add a record, both options A and B are available.
You may also edit the record later, however: I want to allow to switch from A to B, but not to switch from B to A!

How would I do that safely & nicely?

*Note*:

1. *I have a 'rule' => array('inList', array('A', 'B')) in the model*
2. *I don't want a solution that can be altered from an 'Inspect element' modifitation on the front-end or otherwise made Post action*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Write a custom validation rule](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods) with the logic to check that and apply it [on edit only](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#on).

```
public $validate = array(
    'yourField' => array(
        'on' => 'update',
        'rule' => array('checkAandB'),
        'message' => 'You cant go back to A'
    )
);

public function checkAandB($check) { /* your check logic here*/ }
```

Comment: Very helpful direction you've pointed me, thanks! However I can't seem to find the proper way of getting the request data in that public function checkAandB (noob issue). I have ` if ($this->data['Group']['field'] == 'B' && $this->validate['field'] == 'B') { $passed = false ` but that doesn't work. Any clue? Thanks again!

Comment: I mean, how do I get the entered value from the form in this function, I've tried many options like $this->validate['field'] and $this->request->data['field'] and $this->request->data['Group']['field'] ...

Comment: You don't the validation will call that method with the field data for you, it's a callback method (`'rule' => array('checkAandB')`), double check the documentation, it explains that.

Comment: You're right, Thanks - this was the piece I was missing: "The current field to be validated is passed into the function as first parameter as an associated array with field name as key and posted data as value."